# How to define metadata with libcurl?

Tags: c++, http

I do following command with `curl` (the command line tool) to upload a file to google drive:

```
curl --request POST \
    'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart' \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer "..."' \
    -F "metadata={name : 'backup.zip'};type=application/json;charset=UTF-8" \
    -F "@backup.zip;type=application/zip"
```

The following programm with `libcurl` could only use the `URL`, the `header` and upload the file using formdata:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {


        struct curl_slist *chunk= NULL;
        chunk= curl_slist_append(chunk, "Authorization: Bearer \"...\"");
        curl_slist_append(chunk, "Accept: application/json");
        curl_slist_append(chunk, "Content-Type: application/json");

        curl_mimepart *part= NULL;
        curl_mime_type(part, "application/octet-stream");


        struct curl_httppost* formpost = NULL;
        struct curl_httppost* lastptr = NULL;
        curl_formadd(&formpost,
                     &lastptr,
                     CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "sendfile",
                     CURLFORM_FILE, "main.c",
                     CURLFORM_END);


        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
        //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, chunk);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MIMEPOST, part);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, formpost);

        curl_easy_perform(curl);

        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();


    return 0;
}
```

How can I specify the `-F "metadata={name : 'backup.zip'};type=application/json;charset=UTF-8"` in `libcurl`?

I tried it with `CURLFORM_COPYNAME` but this doesn't work.

Comment: Did you read the libcurl documentation for adding FORM data?

Comment: Yes. I added a form data. The file to upload. But I don't know how to define the metadatas in libcul.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the HTTP request's top-level `Content-Type` header to `application/json`, which is wrong.  It needs to be `multipart/related` instead, per Google's documentation: [Send a multipart upload request](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#multipart).

The command-line you showed is inserting a MIME part of type `application/json` into the POST form data, but you are not doing the same thing in your code.

Also, you should not be using `CURLOPT_MIMEPOST` and `CURLOPT_HTTPPOST` together.  Use ONE or the OTHER, not BOTH.  `CURLOPT_HTTPPOST` is deprecated, *replaced* by `CURLOPT_MIMEPOST`. And you are not even passing the correct input value to `CURLOPT_MIMEPOST` anyway.  It expects a `curl_mime*`, not a `curl_mimepart*`.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {
        /* set custom HTTP headers */

        struct curl_slist *header = NULL;

        // uncomment this if you are not using libcurl 7.61.0 or later...
        //
        // header = curl_slist_append(header, "Authorization: Bearer \"...\"");
        //

        header = curl_slist_append(header, "Content-Type: multipart/related");
        header = curl_slist_append(header, "Accept: application/json");

        /* set MIME post content */

        curl_mime *mime = curl_mime_init(curl);

        curl_mimepart *part = curl_mime_addpart(mime);
        curl_mime_name(part, "metadata");
        curl_mime_type(part, "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        curl_mime_data(part, "{\"name\" : \"backup.zip\"}", CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED);

        part = curl_mime_addpart(mime);
        curl_mime_type(part, "application/zip");
        curl_mime_filedata(part, "backup.zip");

        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, header);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MIMEPOST, mime);

        // comment this out if you are not using libcurl 7.61.0 or later...
        //
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BEARER);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_XOAUTH2_BEARER, "...");
        //

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        /* always cleanup */
        curl_slist_free_all(header);
        curl_mime_free(mime);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Or maybe this (I'm not sure the correct way to specify the HTTP `Content-Type` when using a MIME body - documentation and examples are very limited on this topic, most of the examples I found are for SMTP, not HTTP):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {
        /* set custom HTTP headers */

        struct curl_slist *header = NULL;

        // uncomment this if you are not using libcurl 7.61.0 or later...
        //
        // header = curl_slist_append(header, "Authorization: Bearer \"...\"");
        //

        header = curl_slist_append(header, "Accept: application/json");

        /* set MIME post content */

        curl_mime *mime = curl_mime_init(curl);

        curl_mime *rel = curl_mime_init(curl);

        curl_mimepart *part = curl_mime_addpart(rel);
        curl_mime_name(part, "metadata");
        curl_mime_type(part, "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        curl_mime_data(part, "{\"name\" : \"backup.zip\"}", CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED);

        part = curl_mime_addpart(rel);
        curl_mime_type(part, "application/zip");
        curl_mime_filedata(part, "backup.zip");

        part = curl_mime_addpart(mime);
        curl_mime_type(part, "multipart/related"); 
        curl_mime_subparts(part, rel); 

        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, header);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MIMEPOST, mime);

        // comment this out if you are not using libcurl 7.61.0 or later...
        //
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BEARER);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_XOAUTH2_BEARER, "...");
        //

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        /* always cleanup */
        curl_slist_free_all(header);
        curl_mime_free(mime);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This example doesn't work. The title is still `Untitled`

Comment: @JohnSmith you need to be more specific. What EXACTLY does not work? And what title are you referring to? There is no mention of any title in your original question. Worst case scenario, you could (and probably should) just look at the source code for `curl.exe` and see exactly how it translates the command line parameters into specific libcurl function calls.

Comment: I mean the title of the file, which should be created with `curl_mime_data(part, "{\"name\" : \"backup.zip\"}", CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED);`; This doesn't work. The filename is always `Untitled`. I tried to learn from the curl source code, but don't understend it.

Comment: @JohnSmith I don't have access to test libcurl myself right now, but if you capture the raw HTTP request data being sent (see [CURLOPT_VERBOSE](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_VERBOSE.html) and [CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION.html)) and then edit your question to show that data, I can tell you whether or not it is being formatted correctly to what Google is expecting

Comment: I have tried this method and almost all the curl_mime_* functions, but never get the form to send any data... Just hangs perpetually... And no such thing as boundary or any form data in the request headers shown in verbose